# match condition on on foreign collection with lookup in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the 3 collections

```
users: [
{_id: "aaa", name: "John", department: 1},
{_id: "bbb", name: "Charles", department: 1},
{_id: "ccc", name: "Jessy", department: 1"},
{_id: "ddd", name: "Tim", department: 2},
{_id: "eee", name: "Max", department: 2},
{_id: "fff", name: "Julia", department: 2},
{_id: "ggg", name: "Arnold", department: 3}
]

departments: [
{_id: 1, name: "press", society: "times"},
{_id: 2, name: "news", society: "times"},
{_id: 3, name: "infos", society: "herald"}
]

society: [
{name: "times", country: "England"},
{name: "herald", country: "USA"}
]
```

A user work in a department and a department is in a society.

I wanto to do 2 requests, the first one is to have all users from the society "times" and the second, is to have all users from the country "England".

I tried this request for the first one :

```
db.users.aggregate([
{'$match': {'dept.society': "times"}
{
            '$lookup': {
                'from': "departments",
                'localField': "department",
                'foreignField': "_id",
                'as': "dept"
            }
        }])
```

But because of the condition is on foreign collection ("departments"), it seems not working. Only condition on local collection works ('department': 1). How I can do that, and it's the same problem for country request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your two queries.  I also see that you want to begin the aggregations with the `users` collection.

Here's one way to query for:

> all users from the society "times"

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "departments",
      "localField": "department",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "society": "times"  // input society
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "deptLookup"
    }
  },
  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$deptLookup" }, 0 ] } } },
  { "$unset": "deptLookup" }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r746sktlkZ1).

Here's one way to query for:

> all users from the country "England"

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "departments",
      "localField": "department",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "society",
            "localField": "society",
            "foreignField": "name",
            "pipeline": [
              {
                "$match": {
                  "country": "England"  // input country
                }
              }
            ],
            "as": "socLookup"
          }
        },
        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$socLookup" }, 0 ] } } }
      ],
      "as": "deptSocLookup"
    }
  },
  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$deptSocLookup" }, 0 ] } } },
  { "$unset": "deptSocLookup" }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TPz3gbcgNq9).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have some difficulties with lookup. Two more questions : 1) the $unset block the view of deptSocLookup and socLookup, and without it, it will generate an array with values. It is possible to add an $unwind to have a dict instead of an array? 2) I can have society without country, how I can adapt matches if I have a condition on country to have on the answer society with country condition and when country not exist (I think about a $or : {condition, 'country': {$exists: false}})

Comment: @yassinekhelifa You can edit the aggregation pipeline in mongoplayground to see what `"$unwind"` and additional logic would do.  Another great feature of mongoplayground is that you can view the output of each stage by selecting it at the top "Stage by stage output:" drop-down menu.  Note that when you `"$unwind"` an array, a "new" document is created for each array element.  This can be really handy, but sometimes it's better to just process the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I played with mongoplayground and I found what I want and also have a better understanding on lookup and pipeline. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with two lookup

First get society name times and then look up on those two collection

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/q-oCBjm-0hQ

```js
db.society.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "times"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "departments",
      "localField": "name",
      "foreignField": "society",
      "as": "dept_society"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "dept_society._id",
      "foreignField": "department",
      "as": "user_dept"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: the problem I have is that I have simplified all aggregation and in my code, I aggregate on users and then, if I have some queries, I add them. Example : I create a generic aggregation on users, and sometimes I need to add match on user data, sometimes on departments or society. With this solution, match queries impact on the aggregation collection. I saw that I need to use "pipeline" but never succeed in

Comment: I can add three conditions on each collection, that's why I prefer to stay on an aggregation on user, maybe use pipeline to generate condition